# Can I use photos from my current job to promote my own business?

Tags: copyright, employment, business, advertisements

I am self employed but work for a company that does seawalls.  I am the foreman and do all the work with the help of one or more of my boss' employees.  Can I take a picture of the work I do for him and use it for advertising to start my own business doing the same thing.  I build seawalls, stone walls, shoreline landscaping and erosion control.  It's basically landscape construction.  I also tried to find some stock photos to avoid conflict but there are none of the kind of work I do.

Comment: Related question: [Who owns the copyright of a picture taken of my construction work?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/29849)

Comment: Where are you located? Answers to legal questions are highly dependent upon location.

Comment: While this question is largely off topic, it's more of a legal and ethics question than photography. Would you like it if someone were to advertise (without permission) using your work? I (personally) wouldn't. Only way to handle this properly is by asking your current employer.

Comment: I see absolutely no ethical or moral issue with using evidence of work you have completed (whether individually or in a team) to support a business doing that same work. I see no legal issues either (case in point, an acquaintance has done it and checked!) but your general legal jurisdiction and specific employment relationship may vary.

Comment: For that reason, without further information, the question is then too broad, and even with that information, it may verge on being specific legal advice. VTC until the OP can clarify.